# Delete list conditional on the number of elements in R

Tags: r, list, character, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a list `L` of unnamed comma separated character lists. Each list of characters is of unequal length. I need to drop the character lists that have less than 4 elements from `L`. How can this be done? Example `L`:

```
> L
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
[[2]]
[1] "E" "F" "G"
```

In the example above I would like to end up with:

```
> L
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to get the `length` of the `list` elements as a `vector`, create a logical vector based on that and subset the `list`

```
L[lengths(L)>3]
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

A less optimized approach (used earlier) is to loop through the `list` elements with `sapply`, get the `length` and use that to subset

```
L[sapply(L, length)>3]
```

#### data

```
L <- list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[5:7])
```

Comment: How would you apply the first solution to a data.frame?

Comment: @CHRD If you are concerned about the number of rows, `L[sapply(L, nrow) >3]`  as `lengths` return the number of columns or `ncol` for a data.frame