# Remove odd length elements within a list

Tags: r, list, filtering

I have a list and I want to remove the elements that have an odd length:

```
my_list <- list()
my_list$a <- c(1,2,3,4) #length 4
my_list$b <- c(1,2,3) # length 3
my_list$c <- c(5,6,7,8,6,7) #length 6
```

So in the above example, I want to remove  `my_list$b`   because its length is 3 and 3 is odd.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295295/delete-list-conditional-on-the-number-of-elements-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sapply`, imple subsetting and the modulo operator `%%`:

```
my_list[sapply(my_list, length) %% 2L == 0L]
```

Or even better as suggested in the comments using `lengths`

```
my_list[lengths(my_list) %% 2L == 0L]
```

Comment: You can change `sapply(..)` to `lengths(my_list)`

Comment: Cool, I did not know about `lengths`

Comment: Note, that `subset` also works, `subset(my_list, lengths(my_list) %% 2 == 0L)`.

Comment: you may have a even shorter version `my_list[!lengths(my_list) %% 2]`

Answer (score 5):

With `Filter`:

```r
Filter(\(x) length(x) %% 2 == 0, my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer Tidyverse functions, `purrr` has an alternative to `Filter()`:

```r
library(purrr)
my_list |> keep(\(x) length(x) %% 2 == 0)
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 5 6 7 8 6 7
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bitwAnd` to check the odd or even length

```
> my_list[!bitwAnd(lengths(my_list), 1)]
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$c
[1] 5 6 7 8 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just explained the Filter approach mentioned above clearly with the function call.

```
my_list <- list()
my_list$a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
my_list$b <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_list$c <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7)

is_even_length <- function(x) {
  return(length(x) %% 2 == 0)
}

filtered_list <- Filter(is_even_length, my_list)

print(filtered_list)
```